# Mouse coordinates relative to Frame

Tags: java, swing, mouse, coordinates, awt

I'm trying to draw Polygons and would like to be able to click on my Frame to get MouseCoordinates so as to turn a mental Image into x/y values more quickly.

I'm using

```
System.out.println("("+ MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x +",
    "+ MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y +")");
```

but this give me coordinates relative to my actual screen, and not my java window.

How can I make the coordinates show up relative to the Java Window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you add a MouseListener to your frame? Then you can just get the relative coordinates with MouseEvent.getPoint

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getPoint());
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, but it's not giving me the correct coordinates. To test it out I drew a square at x=50 and 7=50(g.drawRect(50,50,100,100)); and when I clicked the top left corner of the square, it save me x=58 and y=78 (java.awt.Point[x=58;y=78])

Comment: That's because you get the mouse coordinates relative to the JFrame but you don't paint directly on the frame. You probably paint on a JPanel that you added to the JFrame. That means you have to add the MouseListener to that JPanel to get the right coordinates.

Comment: my bad, I got frame and panel confused, it's fixed now

Answer (score 13):

You can convert between screen and component coordinates using the [SwingUtilties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) class

The method convertPointFromScreen will take a screen coordinate and convert it to be relative to the component you provide.